# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable when using pandas .values()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, typeerror

I was testing a simple connection from an Amazon Redshift database to my local database using PostgreSQL. I wrote a query to obtain a table from the database, and converted that to a pandas DataFrame. Now, whenever I want to apply some functions on the DataFrame objects, I get the following error. I have tried several times to modify it, and looked up a lot of solutions, but can't seem to work around with it.

```
cur.execute("QUERY for PostgreSQL")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print("Received as rows")
col_names = []
for i in cur.description:
    col_names.append(i[0])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns = col_names)
df.values()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-8e9714b76ea1> in <module>()
---->  df.values()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: remove `()`, need only `df.values`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the prompt reply! How can I use any other functionalities on my dataframe objects? For example, I want an aggregate of the third column but when I use .mean or .aggregate, it doesn't do that. Also, when I do .describe(), it uses the first column, instead of the third column. How can I approach this?

Comment: I think it is a bit broad, the best is create some data sample and desired output.

Comment: But I believe [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) should help.

Comment: @jezrael but it doesn't talk about how I can use just one of the columns to get the .describe() to work or mean() over that one column.

Comment: How about just `df.describe()` or `df['my_column'].describe()`?

Comment: @IanS They don't work, only the basic information is displayed, not the mean, std, min, max etc (this is with `df['my_column'].describe()`). With the .describe(), it only prints the stats for the first column, not the third one.

Comment: If you provide an example to reproduce the problem we can try to help.

Comment: Also ask a new question. This one is no longer relevant.

Comment: Okay thanks! @IanS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [@jezrael pointed out in the comments](/posts/comments/79595696),
`df.values` is not a function, so you don't need to call it. Just use `df.values` instead of `df.values()`.

Comment: Thanks! However, if I want to do a .describe() on my third column of the dataframe, how can I do that?